# How to find sin A, cos A, and tan A by having a basis from a given figure.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I'm a bit confused on how to find the sin A, cos A, and tan A in this figure presented below:

[image]

Since the only given values are 135(side value) and 90 degrees, I'm a bit lost on how to acquire, sin, cos, and tan on it. I tried using Pythagorean formula on getting the hypotenuse first but still I can't seem to figure this one out since it may be on the lack of given values or probably I'm missing something.

Your guides would indeed help me a lot on this one!!! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You can't determine those values from that information alone. But the image looks as if cut-off at the left side. Are you sure that the length of the second leg is not given?

Comment: Alternatively, are the other sides of the triangle required to be integers?

Comment: @user, even if the sides are required to be integers, there are several possibilities.

Comment: @MartinR yes, this is the full figure that I have acquired and I made sure it is not cut-off.

Comment: @user2661923 I guess more likely since one side of this right triangle is an integer. So we probably assume that the other sides are integers as well.

Comment: @GerryMyerson indeed, there are several ways in solving this one, may you share any illustration of a solution to this figure?

Comment: If you go by the *each side an integer* constraint, then the issue would be reduced to whether there is more than one primitive pythagorean triplet having as one of its legs some factor of $(135)$.  The problem would then be solvable iff there is only one such primitive.  Since $(3,4,5)$ and $(5,12,13)$ are both primitive, the integer constraint is insufficient to make the solution unique.

Comment: Re previous comment, the problem is *perhaps* save-able if, *consistent* with the diagram, you also require that the factor of $(135)$ in the primitive pythagorean triplet is **the long leg**.  Unclear, I haven't focused on this issue.

Comment: Integer-sided triangles have sides $2kmn$, $k(m^2-n^2)$, and hypotenuse $k(m^2+n^2)$. $135$ isn't the hypotenuse, and it can't be $2kmn$ since that's even, so all we have to look at is $k(m^2-n^2)=135$. With $k=1$, the solutions (with $\gcd(m,n)=1$) are $(m,n)=(68,67)$ and $(m,n)=(16,11)$. If $k=3$, then $(m,n)=(23,22)$ or $(m,n)=(7,2)$. $k=5$ yields $(m,n)=(14,13)$. $k=9$, $(m,n)=(8,7),(4,1)$; $k=15$, $(m,n)=(5,4)$; $k=27$, $(m,n)=(3,2)$; $k=45$, $(m,n)=(2,1)$. But I really think we're barking up the wrong tree, and the answer is meant to be in terms of $s$ and $h$.

Comment: And why haven't you asked whoever gave you this stupid problem to clarify it for you?

Comment: Are you still here, Ralph?

Comment: Hello @GerryMyserson, excuse me for the late reply, this question was just given from our quiz and its just about to be clarified since were still waiting for the response from our teacher. But probably I assume this question is more likely undefined in some way.

Comment: OK, Ralph. Let us know when you find out, OK?

Comment: Hello @GerryMyerson , I know its a bit late but the answer that was given from our teacher would be:
sin A=s/h, cos A=135/h, tan A=s/135

(more likely, the process did not try to find out the values of s and h, it was left as it is.)

Comment: OK, so, it looks like I was right when I suggested the answer was meant to be in terms of $s$ and $h$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes yes indeed.